# bind() in tkinter does not return the expected value

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to pass a variable with a tkinter `bind()` event on a spinbox. While debugging, I discovered that **I failed in passing the variable to the spinbox `bind()` event handler function**. Indeed, the `print var` line of my handler function `puteventqueue()` prints **0** (the default spinbox value) no matter the value displayed by the spinbox.

Any ideas as to how to correct my mistake are welcome! I must be doing an obvious mistake, but I've been searching for hours...

The spinbox event handler function:

```
def puteventqueue(var):
    print 'spinbox has been clicked'
    print var
```

The spinbox definition:

```
#spinboxes for color filters
spinval = tk.IntVar()
s = tk.Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=180, textvariable=spinval, increment=5)
filters = spinval.get()
s.grid(column=3, row=0)
s.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: puteventqueue(filters))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because filters is already set to 0, and never changed.

Try following:

```
 s.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: puteventqueue(spinval.get()))
```